# how to access to arachni scanner web interface?

Tags: vulnerability-scanners

I have downloaded Arachni package. It is said in the README file to run bin/arachni_web to access to web interface of this scanner.

I run it but no web page appears. I just see these lines:

```
>> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:9292, CTRL+C to stop
```

and then nothing happens.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've started a web **server** listening on port `9292`, that's what the output says. Now you need to connect to it with a web **client** (browser) on that port. Try with `http://localhost:9292`, if you're accessing on the same computer you're running your server on, or replace `localhost` with the IP address on which the server is running (after making sure you're not firewalling selected port, in your case `9292`).

[image: Arachni dashboard]

[Wiki of Arachni's Web User Interface](https://github.com/Arachni/arachni-ui-web/wiki)

Comment: wow,thank you. is it a good scanner?

Comment: @hd. - It will most certainly have your basic needs covered, possibly more. By the way, your question is slightly off-topic as it's not really security related, but about use of a security tool, which IMO is well covered in manuals and online documentation, so not even a good question for [SU] on grounds of not much research being done on your part before asking the question. Since it wasn't much of a bother posting an answer, and it didn't really fit in the comments - well, I did. But I wouldn't be too surprised, if it will eventually be closed as either off-topic or not constructive. ;)